# color multirow in a table

Tags: tables, color

I am trying to color a multirow in my table, but without success until now:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Type} \\
\hline
  & A  &    B & C & D \\
    \hline
    X & 53,2\%  &   51,6\%  &  \multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.9}49\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}49\% }\\
    Y  & 53,8\%  &  52,2\%  &  & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What should I do, so that the two last multirow-cells get completely grey-colored?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Type} \\
\hline
  & A  &    B & C & D \\
    \hline
    X & 53,2\%  &   51,6\%  & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}  & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\\
    Y  & 53,8\%  &  52,2\%  & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{.9}49\%} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}49\% }\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

First color the upper cells by issuing `\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}` and then use `\multirow` n the second row. Note `-2` in `\multirow{-2}{*}{...}`. This will make multi row to grow upwards.

Answer (score 3):

You do that easily with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcccc}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rectanglecolor[gray]{0.9}{3-4}{4-5}
\Body
  \Block{1-5}{Type} \\
  & A  &    B & C & D \\
  X & 53,2\%  &   51,6\%  & \Block{2-1}{49\%}  & \Block{2-1}{49\%} \\
  Y  & 53,8\%  &  52,2\%  & \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

- You need two compilations.
- You won't have artefacts in some PDF viewers as you have sometimes with PDF created by the tools of `colortbl`.

[image: Output of the above code]

It's also possible to use the key `fill` of the command `\Block`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcccc}[hvlines,color-inside]
  \Block{1-5}{Type} \\
  & A  &    B & C & D \\
  X & 53,2\%  &   51,6\%  & \Block[fill=[gray]{0.9}]{2-1}{49\%}  & \Block[fill=[gray]{0.9}]{2-1}{49\%} \\
  Y  & 53,8\%  &  52,2\%  & \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.