# Coloring in a multirow

Tags: tables, color, multirow

I am using TexStudio with Bibtex. I want to color a multirow table. While, I have seen some questions put up earlier in this forum about that, however still I am not able to resolve the problem.

The code for a small sample table is given as follows:

```
 \begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Methods} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Example 1} \\ \cline{2-4} 
& ISE      & IAE      & ITAE     \\ \hline
    Abc                      & 0.1      & 0.2      & 0.3      \\ \hline
    Xyz                      & 0.4      & 0.5      & 0.6      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Please guide me how to color the cell containing the word "Methods"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? (cf. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171785/121799).)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl,multirow,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\cellcolor{red!50}  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ Example 1} \\ \cline{2-4} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{red!50} Methods} & ISE      & IAE      & ITAE     \\ \hline
    Abc                      & 0.1      & 0.2      & 0.3      \\ \hline
    Xyz                      & 0.4      & 0.5      & 0.6      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to color the cell having the word "Methods". When I use \cellcolor{red!50}  to color methods, it colors only half of it. I want to color the complete cell "Methods"

Comment: @ShiS Sorry about this. Changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines,color-inside]
\Block[fill=red!50]{2-1}{Methodes} & \Block{1-3}{ Example 1} \\ 
     & ISE & IAE & ITAE \\ 
 Abc & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3  \\
 Xyz & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.6  
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

You will have a perfect output, in all the PDF viewers.